# Does the .OpenReadStream() method of IFormFile return new streams every time it is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an `IFormFile`, and I want to get its content as a stream using the `OpenReadStream()` method. An operation I do moves the current position to the end, but I need a new stream.

If I call the `OpenReadStream()` method again, will this new stream start at the beginning, or at the last location it was at?

Comment: Considering `Stream` is `IDisposable` it would make sense for a new stream to be returned each time

Comment: why not call this method two times and then assert with "ReferenceEquals(...)" if the returned streams are the same object ? or check the position of both streams. but i'd side with @MickyD, it makes more sense to get a new stream every time you call that method

Comment: Generally you can't re-read data coming from network... I'd expect failures of all kinds trying to read uploaded file twice...

Comment: Could you show your code and explain it more ?Or do you use `using (var reader = new StreamReader(image.OpenReadStream()))`?